# Trouble with str_replace within an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, str-replace, substr

I'm having some trouble using str_replace within an if statement. I'm wanting to remove plural formatting ('s) from some text I'm outputting.

I supply a keyword that is included with the text output. So if my keyword has an 's' as the last character I want the plural characters stripped from the output. For example if the keyword is 'handbags' I'm wanting to echo "I love handbags" rather than "I love handbags's". This is what I've come up with but it does not work.

```
<?php
$keyword = "handbags";

$string = "I love $keyword's.";

$last = substr($keyword, -1);

if ($last == "s") {str_replace("'s", "", $string);}

echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: str_replace returns the replaced value, it doesn't modify `$string`. So you'll have to do `$string = str_replace(...)`

Comment: The major flaw here is that [`'s` is **not** a plural suffix, but a possessive suffix](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling).

Comment: @Tomalak hahaha, well spotted! :)

Comment: Fit gravatar, so I'll let you off ;)

Comment: Note that in addition to the possessive vs plural `s`, this breaks with all kinds of plurals such as "mices" "mooses" and enything requiring `es` ( see: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_plurals_ending_in_%22-es%22 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ($last == "s") { $string = str_replace("'s", "", $string);}`

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace` returns a value and does not act on the string by reference. You need to assign the result back to the string:

```
$string = str_replace("'s", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
$string = "I love $keyword".(substr($keyword, -1)=="s"?".":"'s.");
```

saves you a couple lines of code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is correct variant:

```
    <?php
$keyword = "handbags";

$string = "I love $keyword's.";

$last = substr($keyword, -1);

if ($last == "s") {$string=str_replace("'s", "", $string);}

echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$keyword = "handbag";
$string = "I love $keyword";

$string_count = strlen($string)-1;
$string_check = substr($string,$string_count,1); 

if($string_check == "s"){
    $string = str_replace("s", "'s", $string);
    echo "$string.";
    }
    else {
    echo $string."'s.";
}
```